# how to add authentication to my dockers (one for alll/for each)?

Tags: authentication, docker

I'm learning to use docker, so far I installed several services trough dockers on my computer :

[image]

I'd like to add some authentication (username+password) to them when somebody access them trough their web services. As you can see on the screenshot, I have already several dockers, and they will grow in number...

So, the best would be to setup something, somewhere, a docker or on the host, and to have all dockers using the same authentication.

If, it's not possible, well, I would like to know how I can add authentication.

Comment: If you're talking about a centralized authentication scheme by which users can log in to a specific service with a username/password that may be shared across all services ... there is no single answer. Though you can provide LDAP/AD or SAML, I'm confident all apps will act differently in requiring authentication. (Redis, for example, "[does not try to implement Access Control](https://redis.io/topics/security)", instead only offering a [single password](https://redis.io/commands/auth) for controlled access.)

Comment: Though [owncloud does support LDAP](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/9.0/admin_manual/configuration_user/user_auth_ldap.html) (strongly urge you to not stay with v8.1), portainer [does not (yet) support LDAP](https://github.com/portainer/portainer/issues/677), and ethercalc says that [user/pass management is the role of a CMS](https://github.com/audreyt/ethercalc/issues/294). This suggests that some of your apps will need to be behind an apache or nginx password-wall; but if you put owncloud behind it, things will almost certainly break.